# mean.io / angularjs (routing with $stateProvider)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-ui-router, mean.io

sorry to bother:

i've just spent a few days learning angularjs and (wow) managed to get mean.io running.

now i just can't believe i'm not able to add a new route to the example app (with authentication).

i mean, very simple:

if in the (\views) list.html page this link states:

```
list items if .length > 0 ... else
<h1 data-ng-hide="!articles || articles.length">No articles yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/articles/create">Create One</a>?</h1>
```

and this route is defined in the (\routes\)articles.js as

```
$stateProvider
        .state('all articles', {
            url: '/articles',
            templateUrl: 'articles/views/list.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }
        })
        .state('create article', {
            url: '/articles/create',
            templateUrl: 'articles/views/create.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }
        })
        ...
```

(note1: the url for the create html template is actually /articles/public/views/create.html, but this code works, don't ask me why;

note2: the name / "link" ('create article') is used to call this page also from the header navi(gation)

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in menus.main" ui-route="/{{item.link}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}"><a mean-token="item.link" ui-sref='{{item.link}}'>{{item.title}}</a></li>
```

whereas 'Create New Article' (.title) is added to the menus-var in app.js with link = 'create article'

well, all ok so far, but why if i make a simple change/enhancement in the view and try

```
<h1 data-ng-hide="!articles || articles.length">No articles yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/articles/create">Create One</a>?</h1>

<h1 data-ng-hide="!articles || articles.length">No articles yet. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/articles/create2**">Create Two</a>?</h1>
```

and add to the $stateProvider

```
.state('create article2', {
            url: '/articles/create2',
            templateUrl: 'articles/views/create.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }
        })
```

I get an error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "create2" at path "_id", even if I make a copy of create.html, name it create2.html, change it in templateurl, empty it all out (without Ctrl'er), etc.
of course the create.html-template has a ArticleController attached (in the "html code"), but as much as I know this shouldn't be a problem.

the error "ObjectId failed" ... at path "_id" occurs at mongoose/...objectid.js); i'd guess it's got something to do with the session object or more likely the authencation module.

Many thanks if someone minds to tell me what i'm missing, ... (can't find any useful doc's for mean.io beginners)